# Setup ESP-IDF Tools 2.3 ended up with error code 128

Tags: esp32, esp-idf, esptool

When I try to install esp-idf and tools for my windows 7 64bit verssion, I get this error:
*Installation has failed with exit code 128*

[image: Setup esp-idf]

Here is a part of the log...

```
2021-01-22 13:43:52.756   --------
2021-01-22 13:43:52.756   Resetting the submodules: D:\Git\cmd\git.exe -C D:\esp\esp-idf4.1 reset --hard
2021-01-22 13:43:56.589   Done, exit code=128
2021-01-22 13:43:56.589   --------
2021-01-22 13:43:56.589   Running command: D:\Git\cmd\git.exe -C D:\esp\esp-idf4.1 submodule foreach git reset --hard
                          Entering 'components/asio/asio
                          HEAD is now at 3b66e5b0 Simple ESP32 ASIO port excluding SSL and termio
                          Entering 'components/bootloader/subproject/components/micro-ecc/micro-ecc
                          HEAD is now at d037ec8 Add note that uECC_VLI_NATIVE_LITTLE_ENDIAN affects key compatiblit
                          Entering 'components/bt/controller/lib
                          HEAD is now at 238fc04 Fix ble disconnect due to instant of channel map update is too small(219866f
                          Entering 'components/bt/host/nimble/nimble
                          HEAD is now at fead24e5 Merge branch 'nimble/log_level_filtering' into 'nimble-1.2.0-idf
                          Entering 'components/cbor/tinycbor
                          HEAD is now at d2dd95c Fix compilation error in the documentatio
                          Entering 'components/coap/libcoap
                          error: unable to create symlink README: Permission denie
                          error: unable to create symlink examples/contiki/coap_config.h: Permission denie
                          error: unable to create symlink examples/lwip/coap_config.h: Permission denie
                          fatal: Could not reset index file to revision 'HEAD'
                          fatal: run_command returned non-zero status for components/coap/libcoa
                          
                          
2021-01-22 13:43:56.589   --------
2021-01-22 13:43:56.589   Message box (OK):
                          Installation has failed with exit code 128
2021-01-22 14:55:39.090   User chose OK.
2021-01-22 14:55:39.094   Message box (Yes/No):
                          Installation log has been created, it may contain more information about the problem.
                          Display the installation log now?
2021-01-22 14:55:41.155   User chose Yes.
2021-01-22 14:55:41.186   CurStepChanged raised an exception.
2021-01-22 14:55:41.213   Need to restart Windows? No
2021-01-22 14:55:41.221   Exception message:
2021-01-22 14:55:41.221   Message box (OK):
                          Out Of Range.
2021-01-22 14:55:41.258   User chose OK.
2021-01-22 14:55:41.260   Deinitializing Setup.
```

What does it means ? it installed corectly or not ?

PS: I tried with both V4.1 and V3.3 realeased versions of esp-idf, but with same ending.

Comment: You can also post on esp32.com, this is where most of the Espressif developers hang around. Chances are that you get a quicker answer over there.

Comment: The real error message is half-visible under the modal dialog box. How about moving it and copy-pasting the real error messages.

Comment: If the installer is not working for you, try to follow the instructions for installing the tools by hand (just take in mind that esp-idf does not like spaces in the path): https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/stable/esp32/get-started/windows-setup-scratch.html#get-esp-idf

Answer (score 0):

Run as administrator. It appeared to work for me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).